# Stacked Card View like notifications in new Linked in app

Tags: android, xml, layout, androiddesignsupport

I was going through new Linkedin app when I found a cool stacked cardView on for notifications on My Profile.
 I wonder how to acheive this?
Is this a **new design support library** feature? 
I can also see similar thing on recent apps screen. (Both screenshots attached)

Just an idea / help / approach to acheive this would be helpful.

[image: Linkedin 's new app view]

[image: Android Recent apps view]

Comment: A Horizontal RecyclerView with cardlayout? I suppose

Comment: For your second example, you can check com.android.systemui package, which can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents)  - Open Source power!

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView)

Comment: an [older one](http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html#.VnPw8yArJhE) too